# calculate grades based on users Average Marks in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I've data like below

```
[
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("60a75a2b9b1e0e4a8cd8ac19"),
        "name": "Hrithik",
        "avgMarks": 70
    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("60a75a2b9b1e0e4a8cd8ac20"),
        "name": "Roshan",
        "avgMarks": 78
    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("60a75a2b9b1e0e4a8cd8ac21"),
        "name": "Mahesh",
        "avgMarks": 40
    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("60a75a2b9b1e0e4a8cd8ac22"),
        "name": "Nagesh",
        "avgMarks": 90
    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("60a75a2b9b1e0e4a8cd8ac22"),
        "name": "Ramesh",
        "avgMarks": 99
    }
]
```

and my grades distribution conditions are

80 - 100 ==> A grade

65 - 79  ==> B grade

50 - 64  ==> C grade

35 - 49  ==> D grade

0  - 34  ==> E grade

and my expecting results are

```
[
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("60a75a2b9b1e0e4a8cd8ac19"),
        "name": "Hrithik",
        "avgMarks": 70,
        "grade":"B"
    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("60a75a2b9b1e0e4a8cd8ac20"),
        "name": "Roshan",
        "avgMarks": 78,
        "grade":"B"
    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("60a75a2b9b1e0e4a8cd8ac21"),
        "name": "Mahesh",
        "avgMarks": 40,
        "grade":"D"
    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("60a75a2b9b1e0e4a8cd8ac22"),
        "name": "Nagesh",
        "avgMarks": 90,
        "grade":"A"
    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("60a75a2b9b1e0e4a8cd8ac22"),
        "name": "Ramesh",
        "avgMarks": 99,
        "grade":"A"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation method with [$switch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/) case operator,

- make a helper function to get `$and` condition with `$gte` start number and `$lte` end number to reuse the same function in each case by passing numbers in parameter,

```
function getCondition(start, end) {
  return {
    $and: [
      { $gte: ["$avgMarks", start] },
      { $lte: ["$avgMarks", end] }
    ]
  };
}

let result = await YourModel.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      grade: {
        $switch: {
          branches: [
            {
              case: getCondition(80, 100),
              then: "A"
            },
            {
              case: getCondition(65, 79),
              then: "B"
            },
            {
              case: getCondition(50, 64),
              then: "C"
            },
            {
              case: getCondition(35, 49),
              then: "D"
            }
          ],
          default: "E"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rFVb1Px-6Sx)